# Is it possible to use dynamic_cast for template type checking?

Tags: c++

```
    template <class T> void checkObject(T genericObject)
    {
      MyClassA* a = dynamic_cast<MyClassA*>(genericObject);
      if (a != NULL)
      {
        //we know it is of type MyClassA
      }
      MyClassB* b = dynamic_cast<MyClassB*>(genericObject);
      if (b != NULL)
      {
        //we know it is of type MyClassB
      }
    }
```

Is something like this possible? where we have a template type but we want to know it's actual type?

Comment: Yes, its possible, but it would most certainly be a bad design choice. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: You could also overload the function and get a compile time check.

Comment: @K-ballo: It's only possible if the classes have virtual functions isn't it?  Otherwise isn't it UB?

Comment: @MooingDuck: indeed, I wrote that in my answer (not sure about UB, I think you would get a compilation error)

Comment: @BoPersson: I think the whole point here is to get a *runtime* check (I might be wrong though). He might want to pass in either a pointer to a superclass of `MyClassA` or a pointer to a superclass of `MyClassB` and do the dynamic check. Just trying to interpret though, the goal is kind of ambiguous.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Indeed, it shall be a pointer to or an lvalue of a polymorphic type

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the world of templates you probably want to just specialize templates for each of your types instead of doing a runtime check, ie

```
 template<typename T>
 void foo(T obj);

 template<>
 void foo<MyClassA>(MyClassA obj) {
 }

 template<>
 void foo<MyClassB>(MyClassB obj2) {
 }
```

This will allow the compiler to generate the correct template at compile time by deducing on your args.

Note **this only resolves based on a instance's static type**, that is there's no compile-time knowledge that your variable is a `MyClassC` which inherits from `MyClassB` and therefore should use the generic form. So this won't work:

```
  MyClassC* cinstance = new MyClassC();
  foo(cinstance); //compiler error, no specialization for MyClassC
```

In general this points to a general rule that compile-time and run-time polymorphism are very different systems. Templates deal strictly in the realm of static types without knowledge of inheritance. This may surprise folks coming from Java/C# which have a more seamless integration between the two features.

For run-time specialization of functionality for a class, your options are

1. Define virtual methods -- may not be appropriate depending if this bit of functionality truly should be a part of this object
2. Use dynamic_cast (what you're currently doing) -- somewhat frowned upon, but can be the most straight-forward solution that everyone gets.
3. [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) -- a design pattern that uses overloading to resolve to a function of the correct type at run-time.

Comment: The specialized version of `foo` will only be invoked if called with explicit template arguments. Plus it would only work for `MyClassA`, not for things that _are a_ `MyClassA`.

Comment: @K-ballo, normal function overloading would deal with that. No need for templates for such simple case.

Comment: @Tomek: Yeah, that's my point exactly... Regular function overloading will do, as long as there is no template overload involved.

Comment: Yeah the problem is it's a large function, and I want to reuse the same code. whats the real danger with casting? (Sorry from a java background)

Comment: @K-ballo I edited this extensively to clarify that the templating system doesn't have any knowledge of the run-time polymorphism going on. Hope that clears things up.

Comment: @DougT.: Don't specialize function templates, they don't do what you think they do... Use regular function overloads instead

Comment: @tuck: Well obviously, move the similar code to a function that they both use.  Or call the separate functions from the similar code.  DO NOT HAVE COPY PASTED CODE.

Comment: @tuck: The problem with casting like you do is (A) it doesn't work with most types (B) on types where it does work, that's slow, and (C) what if someone adds another type and doesn't know about your function?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible but `MyClassA` and `MyClassB` **must have at least one virtual member function** in order for `dynamic_cast` to work. I also believe you actually want to have (`T* genericObject`) rather than `T genericObject` in your function's signature (it would make little sense otherwise).

Solutions based on template specializations are OK for ***static* polymorphism**, but I believe the question is how to enable ***run-time* detection** of the input's type. I imagine that template being called with a pointer which is of a type that is either a superclass of `MyClassA` *or* a superclass of `MyClassB`. **Template specialization would fail** to provide the right answer in this case.

Anyway, I have a strong feeling that you are trying to do the wrong thing to achieve what you want to achieve (whatever it is). When you post this kind of questions, I suggest you to make clear **where** you want to go, what is your *goal*; this one might just be an obstacle *along the wrong path*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible. Please note that dynamic cast happens during runtime and templates generate code durign compilation. Thus the function will still be generated but will do checks during runtime for the cases you describe.

EDIT: have a look at Doug T.'s answer for the right way to do what you try to do.